# If i use the video on Youtube, how does the google marketing api fill the AdVideoAsset object

Tags: java, google-analytics

```java
private void createAppAd(
            GoogleAdsClient googleAdsClient, long customerId, String adGroupResourceName) {
        // Set up video
        AdVideoAsset adVideoAsset = AdVideoAsset.newBuilder().setAsset("").build();
        AppAdInfo appAdInfo = AppAdInfo.newBuilder()
                .addAllHeadlines(
                        ImmutableList.of(
                                AdTextAsset.newBuilder().setText("test").build(),
                                AdTextAsset.newBuilder().setText("test").build()))
                .addAllDescriptions(
                        ImmutableList.of(
                                AdTextAsset.newBuilder().setText("test").build(),
                                AdTextAsset.newBuilder().setText("test").build()))
                .addYoutubeVideos()
                .build();
        Ad ad = Ad.newBuilder().setAppAd(appAdInfo).build();
        AdGroupAd adGroupAd =
                AdGroupAd.newBuilder()
                        .setStatus(AdGroupAdStatusEnum.AdGroupAdStatus.ENABLED)
                        .setAdGroup(adGroupResourceName)
                        .setAd(ad)
                        .build();
        AdGroupAdOperation operation = AdGroupAdOperation.newBuilder().setCreate(adGroupAd).build();
        try (AdGroupAdServiceClient adGroupAdServiceClient =
                     googleAdsClient.getLatestVersion().createAdGroupAdServiceClient()) {
            MutateAdGroupAdsResponse response =
                    adGroupAdServiceClient.mutateAdGroupAds(
                            Long.toString(customerId), ImmutableList.of(operation));
            log.info("Created an ad group ad with ad with resource name '%s'%n", response.getResults(0).getResourceName());
        }
    }
```

[Official interface document](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/app-campaigns/create-ad-group)

When I checked the document, I didn’t find the interface to upload or get the material from youtube and filled the result into the **assert** field in **AdVideoAsset**.

```java
  AdVideoAsset adVideoAsset = AdVideoAsset.newBuilder().setAsset("").build();
```

Looking forward to your answer

Comment: maybe you can be more lucky at https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api

Comment: yes,I have solved this problem by looking at the official documents  https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/assets/overview  and  https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v8/YoutubeVideoAsset. thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by looking at official documents.

[Google Ads](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/assets/overview)

[Google YoutubeVideos](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v8/YoutubeVideoAsset)

Here is my test code

1. Create a YouTube video asset and return the asset ID

```java
 // Create a YouTube video asset and return the asset ID，eg:customers/xxxxxxxxxxx/assets/17064058414
 public String createYoutubeVideoAssert(Long customerId, String youtubeVideoId) throws IOException {
        GoogleAdsClient googleAdsClient = googleAdsClientRegister.getClient();
        YoutubeVideoAsset youtubeVideoAsset = YoutubeVideoAsset.newBuilder()
                .setYoutubeVideoId(youtubeVideoId)
                .build();
        Asset asset =
                Asset.newBuilder()
                        .setName("Jupiter Trip # " + "1234")
                        .setType(AssetTypeEnum.AssetType.YOUTUBE_VIDEO)
                        .setYoutubeVideoAsset(youtubeVideoAsset)
                        .build();
        AssetOperation operation = AssetOperation.newBuilder().setCreate(asset).build();
        try (AssetServiceClient assetServiceClient =
                     googleAdsClient.getVersion7().createAssetServiceClient()) {
            MutateAssetsResponse response =
                    assetServiceClient.mutateAssets(Long.toString(customerId), ImmutableList.of(operation));
            System.out.printf(
                    "The youtube video asset with resource name '%s' was created.%n",
                    response.getResults(0).getResourceName());
            return response.getResults(0).getResourceName();
        }
    }
```

2. create ad group ad

```java
    AdVideoAsset adVideoAsset = AdVideoAsset.newBuilder()
                .setAsset("customers/xxxxxxxxxxx/assets/17064058414")
                .build();
```

In the process of docking with Google ads, we have encountered many problems. If we are interested, we can communicate

Comment: Google ads has been adjusted, and any problem can be discussed